# How to set two decimal point into Bar Entry in Mp android Bar Chart in Android

Tags: android, json, android-volley, mpandroidchart

How to set J SON data in bar entry in two decimal point?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to apply formatted values on axis labels or whole set of values present above bars as bar labels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **The ValueFormatter interface**

The IValueFormatter interface can be used to create custom-made formatter classes that allow to format values within the chart (from DataSets) in a specific way before drawing them.

For using the IValueFormatter, simply create a new class and let it implement the interface and return whatever you want to be displayed from the getFormattedValue(...) method.

**Creating a Formatter**

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // use one decimal
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        // write your logic here
        return mFormat.format(value) + " $"; // e.g. append a dollar-sign
    }
}
```

Then, set your formatter to the ChartData or DataSet object:

```
// usage on whole data object
lineData.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());

// usage on individual dataset object
lineDataSet.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
```

**Predefined Formatters**

- [LargeValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/LargeValueFormatter.java): Can be used for formatting large values >
  "1.000". It will turn values like "1.000" into "1k", "1.000.000" will
  be "1m" (million), "1.000.000.000" will be "1b" (billion) and values
  like one trillion will be e.g. "1t".
- [PercentFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/PercentFormatter.java): Used for
  displaying a "%" sign after each value with 1 decimal digit.
  Especially useful for the PieChart. 50 -> 50.0 %
- [StackedValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/StackedValueFormatter.java): A formatter specifically designed to be used
  with stacked BarChart. It allows to specify whether all stack values
  should be drawn or just the top value.

Comment: I used this but this can not applied show some error

Comment: Show me what kind of err

Comment: Great Anand, please up-vote so other guys better found my solution